# How to show array elements in a spinner instead of array value in android studio with kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database, spinner

i have to show elements of `actes` array in  `acteSpinner` when user select in `categorySpinner`
here is what i've done

```
private lateinit var binding: ActivityActeCreatingBinding

private lateinit var categories: Array<String>
private var category: String = ""

private lateinit var deces: Array<String>
private lateinit var habitat: Array<String>

private lateinit var actes: Array<Array<String>>
private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<Array<String>>
private var acte: String = ""

@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    binding = ActivityActeCreatingBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding.root)

    categories = arrayOf("Décès", "Habitat")

    val categorySpinner: Spinner = binding.acteCreatingSpinnerCategories
    val cAdapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories)
    cAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    categorySpinner.adapter = cAdapter

    deces = arrayOf("Bulletin de décès", "Jugement d'hérédité")
    habitat = arrayOf("Certificat de domicile", "Certificat de résidence")

    actes = arrayOf(deces, habitat)

    val acteSpinner: Spinner = binding.acteCreatingSpinnerActes

    adapter = ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item)
    acteSpinner.adapter = adapter

    adapter.addAll(deces)
    binding.tvtest.text = "liste une"


    categorySpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
        override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {

        }

        override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
            category = categories[position]

            when (category) {
                "Décès" -> {
                    adapter.clear()
                    adapter.addAll(deces)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    binding.tvtest.text = "Liste une"
                }
                "Habitat" -> {
                    adapter.clear()
                    adapter.addAll(habitat)
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    binding.tvtest.text = "Liste deux"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

the problem here is i recieve in the spinner `deces` or `habitat` value instead of their elements

[image: screen view]

Comment: Please edit your question and add your database structure as a screenshot.

Comment: Please only use the `android-studio` tag for questions about the Android Studio IDE itself. For questions about Android programming in general, use the `android` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you have defined the second adapter, which should be

```
private lateinit var deces: List<String>
private lateinit var habitat: List<String>
private lateinit var adapter: ArrayAdapter<String>

deces = listOf("Bulletin de décès", "Jugement d'hérédité")
habitat = listOf("Certificat de domicile", "Certificat de résidence")

adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item)
```